# Conversion of Remotely sensed data to color image

Tags: infrared

Please tell me how to convert a remotely sensed data to color image? ,

or please let me know how to calculate the Infrared value from the remotely sensed data?

Answer (score 0):

the best approach for you is to use ENVI. this software would easily handles Satellite images.band near infrared is just alike to gray images. the value are radiance at that bands.

Answer (score 0):

As the other member had said, ENVI, is an option. So is ArcGIS, GRASS, etc.
However, I mostly use MATLAB. the function imagesc does the trick. Mind it this function cannot simultaneously scale more than 3 bands. So is the case with ENVI, which would ask you to select the bands...

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in MATLAB - imagesc, which will scale the values in your matrix to RGB values. If you data is made up of mutliple spectral bands, select only those bands you want to see and use the imagesc. In this case, it would be quite similar in usage to that in ENVI...!

I mostly use this, than ENVI... in my work.